# Prove G has a length at least 25

Tags: graph-theory

If G has a minimum degree 25. Prove G has a path of length 25.

I know a path has distinct vertices and edges. How do i prove that it has a path equal to the min degree?  Please help with hints so I can work this out/

Thanks

Comment: You either need to state that you have a simple graph or you need to allow a path to reuse vertices.  Otherwise consider a graph with just two vertices connected by $25$ different edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider you have a path of length $k, k < 25$ and that it ends on some vertex $v_i $. Can you add one more edge, that connects $v_i $ to some $v_j $, to your path?

**PROOF**: We will prove what was asked by showing that a path that has length less than 25 can still be prolonged.

Let $v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, v_3, \cdots, e_{k-1}, v_k, e_k, v_{k+1} $ be a path of length $k $, with $k < 25$. We know from the statement that $d(v_{k+1}) \ge 25$ that is, $v_{k+1} $ has, at least, 25 edges going out from it. Because there are only $k$ vertices on your path, there is at least one neighbour of $v_{k+1} $, call it $v_{k+2} $, that you can add to your path, making it of length $k+1$. If $k+1 = 25$, we are done. If we still have $k+1 < 25$, we can repeat the whole train of thought with $v_{k+2} $ until your path has length 25.

Comment: no because then k > 25?

Comment: @miller21 you want to prove there exists a path of size 25. If your path does not have size 25 yet, it would be expectable that the path could be prolonged. You can add another edge; yes. Why?

Comment: so then you can continue to add an edge if the size < 25. So you will be able to continue to add edges to the vertex since the min degree is 25. So the least length it can have is the size 25... i am still confused .. did that make any sense

Comment: @miller21 it kind of made but it wasn't very well worded. You should be able to prove that you can expand your path. If the path has size 4 and ends in $v $, you can add another edge, the path has size 5 and ends in $u $. Then another edge is added, and now it has size 6 and ends in $x $, and so on and so forth. You can prove that this can be done if the size of the path is less than 25

Comment: @miller21 did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: not really.. i am still trying to solve the proof.

Comment: @miller21 do you want me to write the proof? Or do you want another hint?

Comment: can you write the proof?

Comment: @miller21 sure, will do it now

Comment: @miller21 there it goes. Sorry for taking so long. Tell me if you can't get it.

Comment: @miller21 $d $ represents degree

Comment: i needed help with another problem. any chance I can email you?

Comment: @miller21 if this issue was solved, consider accepting the answer so as to close this. You can e-mail me at ptarasmahalas@gmail.com but you can also ask the question here on the site.

Comment: just sent you an email. thanks